# Hightlight and change Color of Text in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, highlight, jtextarea

I have to write a program in which i have to highlight and change the color of the sentence in JTextarea. I have one file called original file and summary file. Original file will be displayed in textarea box and i have to highlight all the sentences of a summary file in textarea box.

I want to be highlighted and coloring text in textarea. Please can anyone tell me how can i do this? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You want to highlight only the text? Or to set a color to the component?

Comment: main purpose is coloring the sentence like red color etc

Comment: means if error comes the the text become red and otherwise color is black or green

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [JComponent#setForeground(Color)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setForeground%28java.awt.Color%29) - But not on `JTextArea`. It's not designed for that purpose. Instead, use a [JEditorPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html) or [JTextPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html).
On these components you can also use HTML tags, like:

```
"<html>My text: <font color=\"blue\">" + myString + "</font></html>"
```

You can change the *background* of the `JTextArea` using [JTextArea#setBackground](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBackground%28java.awt.Color%29) (If that what you mean).

Comment: setForeground() works on all text components, but it changes all the text, not just parts of the text.

Answer (score 5):

You can't change the color of text in a JTextArea. You need to use a `JTextPane`. Read the section from the Swing on [Text Component Features](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html) for some examples.

Comment: Sir someone told me about highlighter.. how possible from highlighter

Comment: A highlighter highlights the background, not the text.

Comment: ok then how i only hightlight the text... just hightlight the text

Comment: I gave you a link to the Swing tutorial. Read the tutorial and download the example code an play with the code.